# change $_SESSION['name'] to $_SESSION['id] by fetching id from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a log in form, that starts with session email. Now since I want to be able to update the email address by a form, without broke the session I need to change the session to the id. The problem is that it wont send me the id value to the session, it only gives me value 1, like this: www.mysite.com/profile.php?uid=1 instead of returning the real id number.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['email']);
    header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_SESSION['uid']);
    die();
}
?> 

<?php 
function fetch_user_id($email){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'");
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return true;
} 
?>
```

Comment: And why is your function returning `true` then instead of the desired value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is storing result i.e. (array) of the result found, what you want is `$row['id']`

Comment: *`$rows` is an array...* would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are returning the value `true` from your `fetch_user_id` function. In order to get the correct results you need to return the users id from the `$row` array.

```
function fetch_user_id($email) {
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'");
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row['uid']; // whatever your user id column is called
}
```